# Mule 4 Write and Read from /tmp directory on Cloudhub usinf File Connector?

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4, cloudhub, anypoint-platform

I want to store data on cloudhub in a temporary file. Is it possible to write and read from this /tmp directory? if yes, can someone tell me how ?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use Object store https://docs.mulesoft.com/object-store/

The /tmp directory may get lost if there is any outage or redeployment or anything which kills the worker. To access it you can use File connector read/write.

Comment: Hello Vibhor, actually I'm trying to store around 53k records and this is a huge data, that's why I need to store on a tmp file. The Object Store is for a small amount of data right ?

Comment: Hi Pat , As per documentation Object Store V2 Allows for an unlimited number of entries. There is no limit on the total size of v2 object-stores.

Stores values up to 10 MB (when Base64 encoded) in size. You can estimate base64 size of a payload as follows: CEILING(base10size * 1024/3) * 4, where base10size is object size in bytes. + Example: A base10 payload size of 7.5 MB converts to 10.24 MB base64.

Comment: To access the /tmp directory on cloudhub with the File connector, I set in the configuration : the working directory: /tmp
and the path to empty. is it true ?

Comment: Yes. File connector can be used as /tmp directory

Comment: Is it possible to append to the object store?

Comment: You can use Object Store ->Retrieve to get the value and then append something and Store it back.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use /tmp directory to store application-specific production data (that too 53,000 records!!).  That /tmp directory is meant for the app to store files and objects temporarily created during app's run, such as temp files created by dataweave during processing of large files.

The better option to deal with such a scenario is to use  ObejctStore v2 which supports maxEntries, expirationInterval and entryTTL when used in CloudHub.  You can maintain unlimited number of key/value pairs per application which the size of each value can be up to 10MB.  See [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/managing-application-data-with-object-stores#semantics-and-storage-limits) for more details on ObjStore v2.